# Entity Framework relationship with data annotations

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys

I'm struggling to get relationships working with EF6 and data annotations.

I have three (3) tables: Theme, ThemeType, ThemeSection

A theme can contain a type and a section, so I've constructed my table as such:

```
Theme
Id: int, autoincrement
TypeId: int
SectionId: int
```

then,

```
ThemeType
Id: int, autoincrement
```

and,

```
ThemeSection
Id: int, autoincrement
```

For my code-first class updates, I did the following:

```
[Table("theme")]
public class Theme: IDomain
{
    [Autoincrement, Column("id"), Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("type_id")]
    public int TypeId { get; set; }

    [Column("section_id")]
    public int SectionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TypeId")]
    public virtual ThemeType Type { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SectionId")]
    public virtual ThemeSection Section { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
[Table("theme_type")]
public class ThemeType: IDomain
{
    [Autoincrement, Column("id"), Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual Theme Theme { get; set; }
}
```

and finally:

```
[Table("theme_section")]
public class ThemeSection: IDomain
{
    [Autoincrement, Column("id"), Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual Theme Theme { get; set; }
}
```

Based on [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) link here, you need to define the ForeignKey(s) in the top-level, which is Theme, and I've done so based on the commented out code, but it does not work. Keep getting an error about multiplicity?

Comment: I think, it caused by `AutoincrementAttribute`, because at this case `Id` is also a `FK` to `Theme`, i.e. it only can equals to `Theme.Id` - not `Autoincrement` strategy.

Comment: What is `[Autoincrement]` attribute? I am familiar with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`, but not that.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the example from Learn Entity Framework, and got it working to an extent, still don't know what I did wrong.